# Show git branch name OR commit id

Tags: git, shell, command-prompt

I am trying to reproduce the behavior of my shell prompt when it comes to showing the current branch name.
I'm here using fish but most shell have this feature.
[image: fish prompt]

If I use the command

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --verify HEAD
```

it returns me

> master

Good!

Now, if I checkout an old commit, my prompt shows
[image: fish prompt]

And if I run the command above again it returns

> HEAD

Which is not what I want. I want `3171f5a` just like the prompt. So I've got a new command.

```
git rev-parse --short --verify HEAD
```

> 3171f5a

Nice! But if I come back to master it gives me

> 617ca76

Do you know if there's a command to give me that output straight away, without an `if` statement checking if the return value is `HEAD`.
(shorten hash or not is fine)

Thank you very much

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari Gives the output `* (HEAD detached at 3171f5a)` which is parsable but I'll wait to see if someone has another idea

Comment: **git branch --list** OR **git branch** OR **git branch -l** 
All do the same thing ie list the branches name and will highlight the current one with * preceding the name.

Comment: You can even go for **git branch -v** to check the last commit which is done  in each and every branch

Comment: See `function fish_prompt` in `/etc/fish/config.fish`. It calls another function to show the branch.

Comment: @ElpieKay Yes I tried that! It just seems to show a variable called `git_branch_name` but I can't find where it's defined. No call to any git command in there sadly

Comment: @MrDos Try `echo (git_branch_name)`.

Comment: @ElpieKay Empty output

Comment: `echo  "$PS1"` should show the way shell does

Comment: @ElpieKay You were right, it worked. It's actually a function that does indeed call two command, the second one if the first one failed... Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one-line way to do this in the shell is to use two separate Git commands:

```
git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD || git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

In the detached HEAD case, the `git symbolic-ref` command fails (while the `-q` prevents it from complaining to stderr) and the second `git rev-parse` command goes on to print the shortened hash ID.

Note that when you are on an unborn branch, the `git symbolic-ref` command succeeds and you get the (shortened) name of the unborn branch.

Comment: Yes that's what my shell, fish, actually does. It works, it's simple enough, it solves my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason git prompt logic is usually wrapped up in a function is that it's not quite as simple as a single git command.  You can get close with something like

```
git log -n 1 --format="%D>%h" |cut -d'>' -f2
```

but looking at this I can't help thinking it's a bit brittle (and you may get some unwanted white space).

The constraint of not using `if` (or something equivalent) may not be entirely realistic here.