# Get the current Git branch name or commit hash if detached

Tags: git

Is there a single command that will print the current branch (e.g. `master`) if there is one, or the commit hash if it is detached? The purpose is to give me something to write down so I can later execute `git switch <branch_or_commit>` to get back to where I started.

This is to be used programmatically, so no scraping of `git status`, Bash pipes or whatever. The answer needs to use the "plumbing" commands, which have guarantees about the format and stability of their output.

Also I should note that there are many many questions asking for each of these thinks individually, but not together. **PLEASE THINK BEFORE CASUALLY MARKING THIS AS A DUPLICATE.**

Here are the things I have tried. The closest is actually `cat .git/HEAD`.

| Command | Output on a branch | Output when detached |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `git rev-parse HEAD` | `cedbe9...` | `cedbe9...` |
| `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` | `master` | `HEAD` |
| `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` | `master` | `fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref` |
| `cat .git/HEAD` | `ref: refs/heads/master` | `cedbe9...` |
| `git branch --show-current` | `master` | (no output) |
| your answer here | `master` | `cedbe9...` |

Comment: How about `cat .git/HEAD | sed 's/.*refs.heads.//'`?

Comment: I mean, yes I could do that. But I'd rather have `git` do it because I think the format of `.git/HEAD` is probably more complicated than it seems.

Comment: Outside of this possibly being a fun exercise, why can't you use two commands with an if statement programmatically? ;)

Comment: Just for fun: `git status | head -1 | awk '{print $NF}'`

Comment: I can - that's what I have done in the end. I just wanted to know if there was an easier way. Also scraping `git status` is a bad idea; the output is intended for humans.

Answer (score 6):

Impossible with exactly one command but possible with two:

```
git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD || git rev-parse HEAD
```

Get the current branch; but if detached get the hash.

Comment: If this is the answer, then the question is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47592077/184546

Comment: @TTT Yep, almost an exact dup. But *torek* extended his previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67813819/7976758) so let's it stay.

Answer (score 4):

> The purpose is to give me something to write down so I can later execute `git switch <branch_or_commit>` to get back to where I started.

You'll need to know whether the thing-you-got-back is a *branch name* or a *commit hash ID* because `git switch` demands the `--detach` flag when using a hash ID, but using `--detach` with a branch name will produce the wrong result.

Thus, you *need* to know whether you're getting a symbolic name:

```
if switchname=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD); then
    detach=
else
    switchname=$(git rev-parse HEAD) || exit  # quit if unborn branch
    detach="--detach"
fi
```

and later:

```
git switch $detach $switchname
```

for instance.

There's a flaw in the above: if you *are* on an unborn branch, `git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD` will produce the branch name, but `git switch` won't be able to switch *to* it.  It's probably wise to run both `git symbolic-ref` *and* `git rev-parse HEAD` so as to detect the unborn branch case.